# display json value in select tag(view) zend framework 2

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, zend-framework2

my model: to fetch the data from database

```
public function getAllProjectDomain() {


        $dbadapter = $this->adapter;
        $sql = new Sql($dbadapter);
        $select = $sql->select();
        $select->columns(array('cmain'));
   $select->from('projcat');

    $selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
        $result = $dbadapter->query($selectString, $dbadapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
            foreach ($result as $row) {
             $entity = array(
            "domain"      => $row->cmain
        );
        $entities[] = $entity;
        }

        return $entities;   

    }
```

my controller:

```
 public function domainAction()
        {
       if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

            $service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserService');
            $result = $service->getAllProjectDomain();
            //it will go to service and the method from table

            $mail = $result;
        }
         $results = new JsonModel(array(
        'mail' => $mail,    
        ));

        return $results;
    }
```

my view:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
        <label for="experience" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Relevant Experience </label>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <select class="form-control" id="experience" name="experience" title="Please select experience">
                 <option value="" selected="selected" >--Select--</option>
         <?php  foreach ($mail as $value) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $value ?>"> <?php echo $value ?> </option>
<?php } ?>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.post("<?php echo $this->url('checkcourse'); ?>", {},
    function(data) {

        if (data.mail)
        {
            document.getElementById('experience').value=data.mail;
        }
        else
        {
             alert('no data');
    }     
    }, "json");
});
```

Here i am trying to display the drop down option. The list of option should come from the datbase. Now i am getting the json value in jquery(view file), but i dont know how to make it to display in select tag.

Comment: do you get alert not data?

Comment: if loop condition is getting true in above code, so else part is not working. but i checked alert in if loop, its working

Comment: the jquery function needs ); at the end

Comment: i missed ); while post this question. My problem is, i dont know how to make select tag's option by the json value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit the view:

```
> <div class="form-group"> 
    >         <label for="experience" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Relevant Experience </label>
    >         <div class="col-lg-3">
    >             <select class="form-control" id="experience" name="experience" title="Please select experience">
    >                  
    > 
    >             </select>
    >         </div>
    >     </div>
```

in the jquery function add this:

```
$('<option value="">'+'Select Action...'+'</option>').appendTo('#experience');
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

                   $('<option value="'+data[i]['mail']+'">'+data[i]['mail']+'</option>').appendTo('#experience');
                }
```

instead of a json model try to return a json array

```
$this->getResponse()->setContent(Json::encode($arrayOfData))
```

Comment: object(Zend\View\Model\JsonModel)#304 (8) {
  ["captureTo":protected] => NULL
  ["jsonpCallback":protected] => NULL
  ["terminate":protected] => bool(true)
  ["children":protected] => array(0) {
  }
  ["options":protected] => array(0) {
  }
  ["template":protected] => string(0) ""
  ["variables":protected] => array(1) {
    ["mail"] => array(2) {
      [0] => array(1) {
        ["domain"] => string(4) "java"
      }
      [1] => array(1) {
        ["domain"] => string(6) "dotnet"
      }
    }
  }
  ["append":protected] => bool(false)
}   // this is the value, which i am getting in controller

Comment: instead of a json model try to return a json array $this->getResponse()->setContent(Json::encode($arrayOfData));